# Using COUNT and NOT IN to find total results

Tags: mysql

Here's my current query I'm using

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts 
WHERE source = 0 
AND account_id NOT IN(SELECT receive FROM actions WHERE follow = '$account') 
AND status = 0 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT
```

I want to somehow do something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts 
WHERE source = 0 
AND account_id NOT IN(SELECT * FROM actions WHERE follow = '$account') 
AND COUNT((SELECT * FROM actions WHERE follow = '$account')) AS `total_received_follows`
AND total_received_follows < max_follows
AND status = 0 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT
```

I basically need to get `COUNT` the amount of rows that have a `follow` value of `'$account'` from the `actions` table I then want to check this value has a lower value than the row `max_follows` from the `accounts` table

I understand that's probably not the correct syntax, but is their anyway I can do something like that using the query I have?

Comment: Explain what you need by words

Comment: you're comparing fields against a simple number. Unless you're numbering your accounts by received totals, that will NEVER work.

Comment: I've gone ahead and updated my question with a words explanation, thanks for support anyway guys

Comment: @aidan I already stated that the syntax I've gone ahead and used could be incorrect, that's why I provided a text form of what I'm trying to acquire

Comment: Think we're going to need some more explanation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused, but here goes... In your second query, you're looking for accounts that don't have any corresponding rows in `actions`? But it also looks like you're trying to find accounts that have less than `max_follows` rows in `actions`. Am I right? You realise this is contradictory?

Regardless, this might be a place to start:

```
SELECT acc.*, COUNT(act.id) act_count FROM accounts acc
LEFT JOIN action act ON act.follow = acc.id
WHERE ...
GROUP BY acc.id
HAVING act_count < acc.max_follows
```

Comment: I've gone ahead and cleaned up my question, I kind of see the direction you're going with this though.

Comment: @Curtis What is the structure of `actions`? What does it represent?